# How can I send bandwidth of client to server?

Tags: cookies, webserver, webclient, server

Is there away for server (web-server of web-page or file server) to know what bandwidth client had during last access or during page/file request? Can this information be sent via cookie or together with page/file request?

I guess this is more of theoretical question, since I want to know if server can provide lower resolution image for clients with bad bandwidth available to them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes; use JavaScript Image onload event to time the download speed of a small image (like a logo), then do something usefull with the result like downloaded a large image if the client has the bandwidth.